# How to Test the API by Token on Postman?

Tags: javascript, json, https, postman, postman-testcase

I want to test my APIs on Postman with the token so, I just write a URL with a POST request. Then select **Authorization** option and Choose `Bearer Token` and paste my token. After that, I choose the raw and JSON option and pass the JSON object but data is not Submitted.[image]

Comment: The warning triangle, next to the type dropdown, is telling you that the POST body language (JSON) and the `Content-Type` header do not match. Did you select a different body type before selecting `raw`?

Answer (score 3):

You may add `Authorization` token value to your header request

Example

[image]

**Edit**

Sending object through body request

In "Body" section click on "form-data" tab and add your key/value pairs.

Click on "Headers" add "Content-Type" as header and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as value.

[image]

Comment: I have already done that, Actually my  Request Header  `Authorization: bearer  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`  so, just pass on header like that but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass `APISecretKey` in your `headers`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Accept` and `Content-Type` with the value of `application/json` on the Headers